# Generalizing matrix transpose in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let `a` be a list in python.

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

When matrix transpose is applied to `a`, we get:

```
np.matrix(a).transpose()
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])
```

I am looking to generalize this functionality and will next illustrate what I am looking to do with the help of an example. Let `b` be another list.

```
b = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

In `a`, the list items are 1, 2, and 3. I would like to consider each of `[1,2]`, `[2,3]`, and `[3,4]` as list items in `b`, only for the purpose of performing a transpose. I would like the output to be as follows:

```
array([[[1,2]],
       [[2,3]],
       [[3,4]]])
```

In general, I would like to be able to specify what a list item would look like, and perform a matrix transpose based on that.

I could just write a few lines of code to do the above, but my purpose of asking this question is to find out if there is an inbuilt numpy functionality or a pythonic way, to do this.

EDIT: unutbu's output below matches the output that I have above. However, I wanted a solution that would work for a more general case. I have posted another input/output below. My initial example wasn't descriptive enough to convey what I wanted to say. Let items in `b` be `[1,2]`, `[2,3]`, `[3,4]`, and `[5,6]`. Then the output given below would be of doing a matrix transpose on higher dimension elements. More generally, once I describe what an 'item' would look like, I would like to know if there is a way to do something like a transpose.

```
Input: b = [[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[3, 4], [5,6]]]
Output: array([[[1,2], [3,4]],
               [[2,3], [5,6]]])
```

Comment: You could use tuples instead of lists to indicate indivisible matrix elements.

Comment: NumPy matrices are always 2-dimensional. Your desired matrix is 3-dimensional.

Comment: Did you change the problem or edit the solution into the question?

Comment: @Asad I just commented below on unutbu's post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your desired array has shape (3,1,2). `b` has shape (3,2). To stick an extra axis in the middle, use `b[:,None,:]`, or (equivalently) `b[:, np.newaxis, :]`. Look for "newaxis" in the [section on Basic Slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing).

```
In [178]: b = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])

In [179]: b
Out[179]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])

In [202]: b[:,None,:]
Out[202]: 
array([[[1, 2]],

       [[2, 3]],

       [[3, 4]]])
```

---

Another userful tool is [np.swapaxes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy-swapaxes):

```
In [222]: b = np.array([[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[3, 4], [5,6]]])

In [223]: b.swapaxes(0,1)
Out[223]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[2, 3],
        [5, 6]]])
```

The transpose, `b.T` is the same as swapping the first and last axes, `b.swapaxes(0,-1)`:

```
In [226]: b.T
Out[226]: 
array([[[1, 3],
        [2, 5]],

       [[2, 4],
        [3, 6]]])

In [227]: b.swapaxes(0,-1)
Out[227]: 
array([[[1, 3],
        [2, 5]],

       [[2, 4],
        [3, 6]]])
```

---

Summary:

- Use [np.newaxis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing) (or `None`) to add new axes. (Thus, increasing the dimension of the array)
- Use [np.swapaxes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy-swapaxes) to swap any two axes.
- Use [np.transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy-transpose) to permute all the axes at once. (Thanks to @jorgeca for pointing this out.)
- Use [np.rollaxis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy-rollaxis) to "rotate" the axes.

Comment: I just changed the output type in my post to match yours. However, if you look at your output it doesn't match with that specified in my post. You could imagine my output to be a column matrix whose items are all lists.

Comment: @rsimha: Indeed, I misread the placement of the brackets. Your desired array has shape (3,1,2). `b` has shape (3,2). To stick an extra dimension (err, "axis") in the middle, use `b[:,None,:]`.

Comment: Thanks. This matches the output in my post. However, I wanted a solution that would work for a more general case. I have posted another input/output. My initial example wasn't descriptive enough to convey what I wanted to say.

Comment: @rsimha this does work in general. It lets you add dimensions as you like, you just have to choose the right set of slicing indices.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Thanks. I will give it a try and get back if I have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the swapaxes. That gives me more to play with.

Comment: I'd also mention the `transpose` method, which can replace a bunch of `swapaxes` calls because it lets you apply a permutation to the axes instead of just a transposition.